# Display div on click (toggle) having difficulty getting it working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I'm, having some difficulty getting this to work.
Basically i want to hide a div, but then display it when the preceding div is clicked, as a toggle not hover.

I've used a previous post as a guide, but I can't seem to get it to work. Total novice with JS so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a fiddle of what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/ss5308b2/3/

```
 <div class="detail-service">
<div class="card-link">
   <h3>Basic Wash</h3>
</div>
<div class="card-content">
 <ul>
     <li>Wash vehicle</li>
     <li>Remove any road dirt and contaminates</li>
     <li>Clean wheels safely with acid free cleaner</li>
     <li>Dry using a non scratch micro fibre cloth</li>
     <li>Spray polish applied to vehicle</li>
 </ul>
</div>
<p>£10.00</p>
```

```
$('.card-link').live('click', function(){
$(this).next('.card-content').toggle();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.card-content').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the jQuery in Fiddle code, and replace code in:

```
$(this).next().toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your code using jquery inside the dom ready, also on your fiddle you weren't including jquery, finally use `on` instead of `live`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.card-content').hide();

    $('.card-link').on('click', function(){
        $(this).next('.card-content').toggle();
    });
});
```

fixed fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ss5308b2/7/

Answer (score 0):

Replace `'live'` with `'on'` delegate ( `live` method was depreciated in version 1.7 ). Given the structure of your code, you don't need `next()` lookup. Just target the class `card-content`.

```
 $('.card-content').hide();

$('.card-link').on('click', function(){
    $('.card-content').toggle();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ss5308b2/8/

Answer (score 0):

i think you just need to add JQuery framework in your fiddle. and your code will run just fine. But you should not use the .live method because it's deprecated as described in [http://api.jquery.com/live/]

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

you should replace it with .on method, if you want to add the click event to dynamically added elements then you could use this code

```
$(document).on('click', '.card-link', function(){
    $(this).next('.card-content').toggle();
});
```